# Export Message Tracking in Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003

How can to export message tracking from exchange 2003 for month with user

Answer (score 0):

There's no mechanism to export message tracking data from Exchange System Manager, unfortunately. Depending on how adventurous you are, the tracking tool is really just a front end for searching the tracking logs that are stored on the Exchange server and these logs are readable by other applications. There are third party tools for analyzing and reporting on this data and I've known folks who have written their own scripts to process them.